# Detecting blank/null values with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

What is the best way to blank out a field with jackson?

I have an class "Event" with field endDate which is a java.util.Date.
Another field is description which a String.

Imagine an instance of class Event which has endDate and description set:

```
endDate: 2014-01-25
description: "HTML5 Seminar"
```

I want to be able to update endDate and description to be blank.

ie. after my REST update request I want my instance of class Event to have blank values for endDate and description.

The following does not work:

```
{
    "endDate": null,
    "description": ""
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you define "blank out"? Do you want to ignore the field when it doesn't have a value?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example

Comment: I understand the example but I am not sure what this has to do with Jackson and the serialization process. If you update the entity as you describe - null for the `date` and empty String for the `description` - the Jackson will serialize the updated entity correctly. So this looks to simply be a standard update operation - is there something I'm missing?